# Unable to install "lodown" in R

Tags: r

My R version is 4.0. Somehow I cannot install "lodown" package following steps in http://asdfree.com/prerequisites.html

```
install.packages( "devtools" , repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/" )
library(devtools)
install_github( "ajdamico/lodown" , dependencies = TRUE )
```

when I typed the last line, my rstudio shows the following message,

```
Downloading GitHub repo ajdamico/lodown@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\dami\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcnnSxn\remotes2658c22728a6\ajdamico-lodown-8cb3f9f/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'lodown': (343ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'lodown_0.1.0.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘E:/dami/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'lodown' ...
** using staged installation
** R
Error : (converted from warning) unable to re-encode 'pew.R' line 131
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'lodown'
* removing 'E:/dami/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lodown'
Error: Failed to install 'lodown' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/dami/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcnnSxn/file2658c65e65d1/lodown_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I install the package? I was able to do that like a year ago, and now it does not work!

Comment: Thanks to Anthony Damico, I found out the problem was system language locale setting. I changed it to english and everything is working now. I leave this comment for future reference. Special thanks to Anthony Damico

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.